# Laravel Echo automatically disconnects first connected user

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-echo, pusher-js, ably-realtime

I'm building a real-time chat using Laravel, Ably (Pusher) and Vue 3 and a presence channel.

Everything works great, but for some reason the first connected client gets disconnected automatically after ~10 seconds (the `leaving` event occurs for that user), but I'm still able to send messages (which are also received correctly by the other connected users).

I'm registering the events in my components, using the `onMounted()` hook (the `user-left` is emitted):

```
onMounted(() => {
    window.Echo.join('room')
      .here((users) => {
        emit('user-joined', users);
    }).joining((user) => {
        emit('user-joining', user);
    }).leaving((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        emit('user-left', user);
    }).listen('.message.new', (eData) => {
        data.messages.push(eData);
        data.message = "";
    }).error((error) => {
        emit('connection-error', error)
    })
})
```

Strangely enough, this only happens for the first connected user. If I open a new tab browser, with a different user logged in, it doesn't get disconnected.

In my `bootstrap.js` file, the configuration is unchanged from Laravel's scaffolding, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there anything I should take into consideration?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue! I wonder if it's a development/local environment issue and not a problem on production build?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for raising the issue!
This is a common problem while using `pusher-js` as a client while connecting to ably in laravel.
You should rather use [official ably-laravel-broadcaster](https://github.com/ably/laravel-broadcaster) that uses native `ably-js` client to connect with ably.
Under [bug-fixes](https://github.com/ably/laravel-broadcaster?tab=readme-ov-file#bug-fixes) section, you can see this issue is already addressed.